# Resize Applied to UV Editor does not Save

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor, saving

[image]

Hello all. I am attempting to resize the skin textures on multiple models. In this instance, I have clicked on the skin mesh and opened the UV Editor. Navigating to Image Resize, I lowered the value to 1024x1024 and then saved the file. However, upon reloading the file, the mesh is back to it's original size.

Comment: When you say "saved the file" do you mean the blend file, or the image file.  Saving a blend file doesn't automatically save image files; you have to do that explicitly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your alacrity, Marty. My apologies for the lack of specificity. By "saved the file", I meant the blend file, not the image file. I had no idea this was a separate option. You have my heartfelt thanks.